# Get related products for a product by category

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to show products related to a category. But it is showing all products which are also related to other categories.

Blade:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        @foreach ($category->products as $product)
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 p-b-50">
        <!-- Block2 -->
            <div class="block2">
                <div class="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative block2-labelnew">
                    <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/backend_images/product_images/{{ $product->product_image }}" 
                        class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 270px; height: 360px;" />
                    <div class="block2-overlay trans-0-4">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="block2-txt p-t-20">
                    <a href="product-detail.html" class="block2-name dis-block s-text3 p-b-5">
                        {{ $product->product_name }}
                    </a>

                    <span class="block2-price m-text6 p-r-5">
                        $75.00
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function products(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    $categories = Category::with('products')->distinct()->get();
    return view('product.listing', compact('product', 'categories'));
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/product/{id}','Admin\ProductController@products')->name('product.products');
```

Comment: FYI a distinct() clause on a Eloquent Model selecting all fields don't do anything because they are all already different at least for the primary key

Answer (score 0):

```
public function products(Request $request, Category $category)
{
     $products = Product::where('category_id',$category->id)->get();
     $categories = Category:all();
     return view('product.listing', compact('products','categories'));
}
```

Comment: Undefined variable: categories (View:

Comment: Show the html code of the button that you are using in order to redirect to the desired page. And the HTML of the desired page.

Comment: <a href="{{ route('product.products', $category->id) }}" class="flex-c-m size2 m-text2 bg3 hov1 trans-0-4">
        {{ ucwords($category->category_name) }}
       </a>

Comment: Check the update now, you are sending the category id in the URL so you should use it in order to get all product that are using that id in the column category_id. You should adapt your HTML code in consequence.

Comment: I think that you should go back to Laravel basics cause all people's answes are correct but you are unable to adapt your code. You just want to copy/paste the correct code.

Comment: hahhaha no I have completed a lot but these are miner issues which are remaining,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Edit your controller:

```
  public function products(Request $request, Product $product)
  {
      $categories = $product->categories;
      return view('product.listing', compact('product', 'categories'));
  }
```

Also you should have the categories relationship method on Product Model.

Comment: yes I relationship in model but now it says Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:

Comment: please provide more information, what I understood was that you want to see a product with it's categories, is that correct?

Comment: no I just wants that when I click on any category then only its related products shown,,,,,,,,it takes the id of that product on next page http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/1   but show all products related to all categories,,

Comment: i just wants to show products related to only that category which is clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function products(Request $request)
      {
          $categories = Category::where('id',$request->id)->with('products')->get();
          return view('product.listing', compact('categories'));
      }

 @foreach($categories as $category)
                        @foreach ($category as $product)
```

Comment: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: use get() instead of first()

Comment: Undefined offset: 1

Answer (score 0):

Your route is

```
Route::get('/product/{id}','Admin\ProductController@products')->name('product.products'); 
//{id} it means you're getting category id from route right? so you can directly access it in controller.
```

**Controller**

```
//$id is from route.
public function products($id) 
{
  $products = Product::with('category')->where('category_id',$id)->get();

  return view('product.listing', compact('products'));
}
```

In your **blade file**

```
@foreach($products as $product)
//here your all product which belongs to that categories.
and now if you want to access categories then may do as.

categories :- {{ $product->category->name }} //make sure it belongsTo in product

@endforech
```

Comment: Edited answer..can you tell why you're compact categories??

Comment: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: Can you tell me this error is comes from ?? controller or blade file?

Comment: controller...……….

Comment: Got your solution??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a product has one category and you have a `category_id` column in your `products` table change `products` method in your `ProductController` like below.

```
public function products(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    $relatedProducts = Product::where('category_id', $product->category_id)
        ->where('id', '!=', $product->id) // ignore current product
        ->get();
    return view('product.listing', compact('product', 'relatedProducts'));
}
```

Replace `id` in your `route with`product`. [Read More about route model binding.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding)

```
Route::get('/product/{product}','Admin\ProductController@products')->name('product.products');
```

Then in your view your you can iterate through `relatedProducts`

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
  public function products(Request $request, Category $category)
  {
    $category->load('products');
    return view('product.listing', compact('category'));
  }
```

route:

```
  Route::get('/product/{category}','Admin\ProductController@products')->name('product.products');
```

blade file:

```
   @foreach ($category->products as $product)
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 p-b-50">
                        <!-- Block2 -->
                        <div class="block2">
                            <div class="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative block2-labelnew">
                                <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/backend_images/product_images/{{ $product->product_image }}" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 270px; height: 360px;" />


                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
```